# How to extract the data from Generic <T> List object

Tags: c#, .net, generics, foreach, generic-list

I wanna create the generic function inwhich I will just pass the class name and get the data in CSV format that is from JSON object on the bases of Generic Class Type.

But I am not able to access the class  member while foreach loop.

```
public class Lifetouch
{
    public int LifetouchID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Lifetemp
{
    public int LifetempID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

main()
{
    getPerodicListofVitalSigns <Lifetouch>(new Lifetouch());
}

public static void getPerodicListofVitalSigns <T>( T clazz)
{
    List<T> list_of_measurements_Original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json_response);

    // Got the list_of_measurements_Original count 2.

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("[");

    foreach (var element in list_of_measurements_Original)
    {
        sb.Append(element.LifetouchID + ", ")  // Not able to access the element of list LifetouchID
    }
    sb.Append("]");
 }
```

Comment: I assume that last `.Append("]")` is supposed to be `sb.Append("]")`?

Comment: You need to apply constraints to `T` to specify what API it supports.

Comment: I am trying but not able to access. Please let me know by the statement if possible for you.

Comment: Well, you are mixing generics with strongly typed classes.  If you want to use `LifetouchID`, you will need to check if `clazz` is of type `Lifetouch` (`var lifetouch = clazz as Lifetouch`), then if not null then `lifetouch.LifetouchId`

Comment: Thanks you very much its working  by as below  :    
var lifetouch = element as Lifetouch;
sb.Append(lifetouch.LifetouchID);

Comment: Why generic, why not just take in a `Lifetouch` to the function?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to create the generic function inwhich I will just pass the class name and get the data (ID's) in CSV format that is from JSON object on the bases of Generic Class Type. That all the ids will pass through webservice and update the database. Its the requirement.

I would like to create the Generic function in which I would like to pass the class name as a paramenter. So in future its easy for me to use that generic function if new class added.

Now its working fine..

```
public class Lifetouch
{
    public int LifetouchID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class Lifetemp
{
    public int LifetempID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

main()
{
    getPerodicListofVitalSigns <Lifetouch>(new Lifetouch());  
    getPerodicListofVitalSigns <Lifetemp>(new Lifetemp());
}
public static void getPerodicListofVitalSigns <T>( T clazz)
{
    List<T> list_of_measurements_Original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json_response);

    // Got the list_of_measurements_Original count 2.

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("[");

    foreach (var element in list_of_measurements_Original)
    {
         if (VitalSignName == "Lifetouch")
                            {
                                var vitalSign = element as Lifetouch;
                                dataString = dataString + (vitalSign.LifetouchID + ",");
                            }
                            else if (VitalSignName == "Lifetemp")
                            {
                                var vitalSign = element as Lifetemp;
                                dataString = dataString + (vitalSign.LifetempID + ",");
                            }
    }
    sb.Append("]");

    string WebserviceAddress = "192..../json/reply/UpdateSyncStatus";
    JSON_POST_Sender.ClassPost(WebserviceAddress, dataString), "true")
 }
```